# Automatic restart PM2 when file change , config.js , data.json

Tags: node.js, pm2

how can i using a command when two file is change and my PM2 automatic restart immediately

config.js file
and
data.json file

right now im using command access on putty for restart it by this command manuals
sudo -u nodejs pm2 restart (appname)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.